# is there a "fail fast" option for flutter tests?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, testing, fail-fast

to save time and money both locally and in CICD
I would like to add "fail fast" to my flutter tests
but I cannot find it in the official docs
is there a way to do that?